# Parse a CloudWatch alert in AWS Lambda Python function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on Lambda function that will perform several actions based on CloudWatch alerts.

The JSON format of the alerts is:

```
{
    'SignatureVersion': '1',
    'Timestamp': '2018-03-08T16: 06: 27.163Z',
    'MessageId': 'df82d564-1651-5dc6-a37a-867f779226ec',
    'Message': '{
        "AlarmName": "awsec2-i-08c38bb8af7962797-CPU-Utilization",
        "AlarmDescription": "Created from EC2 Console",
        "AWSAccountId": "111111111111",
        "NewStateValue": "ALARM",
        "NewStateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [1.49999999999939 (08/03/18 16:04:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0).",
        "StateChangeTime": "2018-03-08T16:06:27.124+0000",
        "Region": "EU (Ireland)",
        "OldStateValue": "OK",
        "Trigger": {
            "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
            "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
            "StatisticType": "Statistic",
            "Statistic": "AVERAGE",
            "Unit": null,
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "InstanceId",
                    "value": "i-08c38bb8af7962797"
                }
            ],
            "Period": 60,
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
            "Threshold": 1.0,
            "TreatMissingData": "",
            "EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile": ""
        }
    }',
    'Type': 'Notification',
    'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1: 11111111111:test',
    'Subject': 'ALARM: "awsec2-i-08c38bb8af7962797-CPU-Utilization" in EU (Ireland)'
}
```

What I need to understand is how I tell my function to extract only the `InstanceId` value and use it as variable for the rest of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Message` is JSON provided as a string. To access the contents of the string, you'll need to use the `json.loads()` function:

```
import json

alert = ... (from CloudWatch)

message = json.loads(alert['Message'])

[msg['value'] for msg in message['Trigger']['Dimensions'] if msg['name']=='InstanceId']
```

However, please note that this will merely output the `InstanceId` that was provided as the **Dimension** for the alarm. It is not specifically saying that this instance caused the alarm (but that is true).

For example, you could create an alarm based on a *group* of EC2 instances. If the average CPU went above a threshold, the alarm would be triggered. However, the dimension would relate to the *group*, not a specific instance.

Think of it as saying *"The Alarm with a filter of Instance i-xxx has been triggered"*, as opposed to saying *"Instance i-xxx triggered the alarm"*.

As long as your alarm is always based on a single instance, then the Dimension will be what you expect.